# Facebook get number of sent requests and accepted request

Tags: facebook

i need to make a page that will have a request dialog for a facebook page or a facebook app.
I need to get the number of friends the user sent the request to and at the end of the day the number of request that got accpeted from the specific user.

The scenario is for giving awards , the user that sent the most request to freinds gets an award and the user that had the most requests accepted also gets an award.

I dont know if the seccond is possible , but i think it should be , couse games on FB give u points for sent request and also u get new missions when friends accept your request , so there mut be a way.

--
I will record the number of invites sent.

Return Data
request_ids

A comma-separated list of the request_ids that were created. To learn who the requests were sent to, you should loop through the information for each request object identified by a request id.

```
FB.ui({
                   method: 'apprequests',
                   title:'Suggest '+fbAppName+' to your friends',
                   message: 'I thought you would dig this app!',
                   data: 'gameID=96'
       }, onInviteFriend);

//jquery required for ajax function
    onInviteFriend = function(response) {
        if (response && response.request_ids) {
            var idsLength = response.request_ids.length;
            var idList = "";
            var data = {};
            var ajaxSettings = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < idsLength; i++){
                idList += response.request_ids[i];
                if (i < idsLength-1){
                    idList += ",";
                }
            }
            if (idsLength > 0){
                data.idList = idList;
                ajaxSettings = {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: sketchnpass.root+"/ajax/log-invite-sent/",
                    data: data,
                    success: sketchnpass.onSaveInvites
                };
                $.ajax(ajaxSettings);
            }
            //was published
        } else {
            //was not published
        }
    }
```

i think using the code above i can get the number of sent requests.

But when some1 accepts the request how will i know that happened , does the accepted request send the user to my app along with some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Facebook requests dialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) basically walks you through how to do this.

When requests are sent, request_ids is returned as return data so you would want to log this information in your system to track who sent how many requests.

To track accepted invitations, the documentation says that this url is called: http://apps.facebook.com/[app_name]/?request_ids=012345678910  so you would just need to parse the request id and look that request id up in your system and mark it as accepted.